# dot net core web api project templates are different

Tags: asp.net-core

I just compared the code generated by `dotnet new webapi` and `dotnet new angular`, and checked only the web api code.

For some reason controllers derive from different classes, in project created with `dotnet new webapi` controller is derived from **ControllerBase**, while in project created with `dotnet new angular` controller is derived from **Controller**

Also the return types for actions are different, in angular template its the **actual return type**, while in webapi template its **ActionResult**

[image]

Why is that?

Which option is the "best"? And why are they different?

Comment: web api is best, for angular it's old style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before .NET Core Web API and MVC controllers were similar.

But starting with 2.0/2.1 Web API was changed.

Now you should derive class from `ControllerBase` instead `Controller` and use  `[ApiController]` attribute.

Old style will continue to work anyway.

Angualar use Web API, I suppose, so template should be updated.

See [WEb API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: But both projects created with the same version of dotnet core... just different templates

Comment: this template will work anyway. If it used Web API, you can change manually.

Answer (score 1):

`ControllerBase` doesn't have any of the Razor/view support. `ControllerBase` is used for APIs.